# Cisco IOS Software [Everest], ISR 4331. Vlan+Vrf+Dhcp

Tags: routing, vlan, dhcp, vrf, cisco-isr

I'm looking after to use a setup with that objectives in mind:

1. Create a subinterface on interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
2. create a Vlan and assign it to that subinterface
3. create a vrrf and assign it to that subinterface
4. declare a dhcp server and attach it to that subinterface.
   4)route to wan from vlan.

The idea is to have a layer 2 and 3 separate isolated virtual networks.

The sites a was reading where:

https://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-vrf-in-cisco-ios-router/

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/multiprotocol-label-switching-mpls/mpls/24508-internet-access-mpls-vpn.html

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucme/vrf/design/guide/vrfDesignGuide.html#wp998688

https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/s/question/0D53i00000Kt2zbCAB/how-to-configure-vlans-on-cisco-router

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/xe-16/dhcp-xe-16-book/config-dhcp-server-xe.html#GUID-0C4F21C0-650F-4652-A621-9FB49202767C

The Code I produced is:

```
enable
configure terminal
ip cef
ip dhcp database disk0:router-dhcp timeout 60
ip dhcp database disk0:router-dhcp write-delay 60
ip dhcp bootp ignore
end


enable
configure terminal
ip vrf VRF200
RD 68686:200
route-target export 68686:200
route-target import 68686:200
ip route vrf VRF200 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.20.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.20.1 192.168.20.110
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.20.210 192.168.20.255
ip dhcp pool VLAN200
   network 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.20.1 
   class VLAN200
   dns-server 8.26.56.26
   dns-server 198.153.192.1
   domain-name localdomain
   lease infinite
   vrf VRF200
   excluded-address 192.168.20.1 192.168.20.110
   excluded-address 192.168.20.210 192.168.20.255
end

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.200
description VLAN200
encapsulation dot1q 200
ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
vrf forwarding VLAN200
duplex auto
speed auto
exit
```

Is just a prove of concept, I'm not experienced on cisco, and evidently this code is not working. I attach a interface to GigabitEthernet0/0/1 from my PC tagged with vlan200 and no ping into GigabitEthernet0/0/1.200 and no dhcp.

Any guide will be very welcome.

Yes, this card can send tagged frames. Used it a lot before. I have a router mikrotik and I can use the vlan200 without problems if I plug the wire into it.

1.Seems up:

```
#show interface GI0/0/1.200
GigabitEthernet0/0/1.200 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is ISR4331-3x1GE, address is 00a3.d1ab.d5dc (bia 00a3.d1ab.d5dc)
  Description: VLAN200
  Internet address is 192.168.20.1/24
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation 802.1Q Virtual LAN, Vlan ID  200.
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Keepalive not supported
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
```

I didn't setup a Spaning Tree so last commands do not aply.

After a few tests I was doing again step by step the config and testing.
The vlan seems ok, and after setup ip by hand I can ping...

```
#ping 192.168.20.111
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.20.111, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/1 ms
```

Them I setup the DHCP server and seems ok too:

```
#Show ip dhcp binding
Bindings from all pools not associated with VRF:
IP address      Client-ID/              Lease expiration        Type       State      Interface
                Hardware address/
                User name
192.168.20.111  0118.31bf.d040.62       Infinite                Automatic  Active     GigabitEthernet0/0/1.200
```

So the problem of my setup has to be related to VRF.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED:**

Here are a few things to check:

Can your PC really send tagged frames (most PCs can't)?

1. Your VRF is named **VRF200**, but your config shows
   **VLAN200**
2. Be sure you enter

`vrf forwarding VRF200`

**before** you enter the ip address

```
ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: That was the solution. thank you ofr the hint :D